# Подключение к WebSocket из Internet explorer

Tags: javascript, windows, websocket, internet-explorer

Мой сайт работает в связке с установленным на клиентские машины приложением. Сайт отправляет в приложение команды через веб сокет, по адресу "ws://localhost:8181". И тут возникает проблема с интернет эксплорером. Сайт разумеется использует протокол "https" и при попытке подключения к вебсокету по протоколу "ws" эксплорер выкидывает исключение "SecurityError". Хром, Эдж и Файрфокс такого не делают и работают без ошибок.
Вопрос: как это исправить наименьшими усилиями? Может быть есть некая настройка в эксплорере которая позволит ему понижать уровень секретности для "localhost"? Я бы просто добавил это в мануал для редких любителей експлорера.

Comment: А зачем вам вам понадобилось оживлять мёртвый Internet Explorer в 2021 году?

Comment: Не такой уж он и мертвый. Есть корпоративные клиенты которые на них сидят в соответствии с security policy компании. А еще в IE работают жава аплеты. Так что хоронить, увы, рано.

Comment: @Infarch - это ж какой java вы пользуетесь? аплеты уж сколько лет выпилены из java...
а websocket  в IE никогда не было и и не будет..  его уже забросили , когда ws  появились.